# ROS installation and usage of nmea_navsat_driver for GPS receiver?

Tags: rospy, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm currently trying to set up a GPS receiver and base station my boss purchased to work in ROS. It is a trimble Ag GPS 542 GNSS receiver (http://ssmgps.com/pdf/AGPB_AgGPS542_BaseAndReceiver_ROW_16502.pdf). It looks like the deivce can work in NMEA-0183 sentences, and thus that it should be compatible with the nmea_navsat_driver ROS package, found here: http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver, but I am encountering some installation issues.

First off, the package is in python, which I've never worked with in ros before (just C++ before now).  Is it a problem to have one node in a project with several different nodes be written in python, while the others are in C++? And if not, what's the general installation procedure for python packages?  I git cloned the source into my catkin_ws, and then ran the lines

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

without issue.  However, when I now to try to test out the package with

```
rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=38400
```

I get the error

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package nmea_navsat_driver not found
```

no matter where I am in the file tree.  This makes me think I have goofed up the installation somehow.

Anyone have any advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190089/ros-installation-and-usage-of-nmea_navsat_driver-for-gps-receiver?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angshumanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/27547/angshumang/) on 2017-02-15**:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver

**Comment by [angshumanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/27547/angshumang/) on 2017-06-16**:
Inside the driver go to this folder :

```
roscd nmea_navsat_driver/scripts/
```

and then make all the files executable by

```
chmod +x *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I needed to extract the package into catkin_ws/src rather than just catkin_ws, because the latter is not in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

Although upon doing this I have now encountered new errors, which I made another question for here:

```
http://answers.ros.org/question/190264/trouble-installing-nmea_navsat_driver-package/
```

---

Originally posted by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) with karma: 170 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0